# Tail bounds on the sum of independent variables with known tail bounds

Tags: statistics

Suppose $X$ is a random variable with mean $\mu_X$ and variance $\sigma_X$
and $Y$ is an independent r.v. with mean $\mu_Y$ and variance $\sigma_Y$.

Suppose further that we have tail bounds on the $X$ and $Y$; i.e. we know that $$\mathbb{P}\left(|X-\mu_X|\ge \alpha  \right)\le g_x(\sigma,\alpha)$$for some polynomial $g_x$ and have the same tail bound on $Y$ for $g_x$.

Is there a natural way to derive the tail bound for $(X+Y$)? That is, what can we say about $$\mathbb{P}\left(|(X-\mu_X)+(Y-\mu_Y)|\ge \alpha  \right)?$$

Comment: With the triangle inequality, you can definitely at least assert this probability is at most $\max( g_x(\sigma_X,\alpha/2), g_y(\sigma_Y,\alpha/2))$. What kind of bounds are you hoping for? (stronger?)

Comment: @ClementC. $\max$ in the sense of $+$?

Comment: I was using it in the usual sense (if $\lvert X\rvert + \lvert Y\rvert \geq \alpha$, at least one of the two must be $\geq \alpha/2$). Does it make sense, or did a make a mistake in the reasoning?

Comment: @ClementC. Indeed $[|X|+|Y|\gt a]\subseteq[|X|\gt a/2]\cup[|Y|\gt a/2]$. And? (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Comment: @Did: so $\mathbb{P}\{\lvert X+Y|rvert > a\} \leq \mathbb{P}\{\lvert X\rvert + \lvert Y\rvert > a\} \leq \mathbb{P}\{\lvert X\rvert > a/2 \} \cup \{ \lvert Y\rvert > a\}$; then indeed I used the $\max$ incorrectly, it should be either the sum of twice the maximum (the sum being tighter). Thanks!